# Repairing items in Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

How is the cost of repairing items calculated? There seems to be a pretty big range.

Also, do repair kits always restore the same amount of damage or does it vary based on item type and quality?

Comment: All i know is that the more damaged the item is the more you pay,also price increases by the quality (rarity) of the items.Now about repair kits i can't really tell you much,all i know is that if you level up your blacksmith skill then repair kits will increase in their effectivneess every BS level.I have 2/3 Blacksmith skill upgraded and i can repair item of any quallity to full no matter how damaged it is with only 1 repair kit.My advice is level up your BS and repair your items only with repair kits,they cost only 60 each,which is LOT cheaper then repairing at NPC.

Comment: Repairing at an NPC basically should never be done.

Comment: Epic items are expensive to repair at the shop, thanks for the comments, I hadn't even tried to use a repair kit.

Comment: Yeah, I've been wondering this... the game says your repair kits are more effective with higher blacksmithing, but even with only 1 point in it, a single kit seems to fully repair any given item.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a complicated question.  Repair kits become essential later on and they also become abundant and very affordable.  The more advanced an item is (i.e. a purp vs a white) the more it will cost to repair it.  When I first started I actually didn't understand repair kits so i had a back up of certain armors and weapons I couldn't repair.  Truthfully, a lot of purps that you acquire will have about 40+ limit for damage.  By the time you effectively get it to 4 or 5 you will have found something superior.  It is also far cheaper to repair crafted armors as opposed to purps and blues and greens picked up along the way.  Repair kits become essential later on and money becomes less of an object.  Right now it costs between 200 to 300k for full repairs but i have almost 6 mil.  Early on, try to have backups and sell old ones or dismantle for parts as you save money and save repair kits.  Once you get to about level 20 is when you will see that it is much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

However the cost of repairing at a blacksmith is calculated, it's too high.

I've never had a repair kit fail to completely repair an item, and they only cost about 50 gold at a merchant. Even at the start of the game, repairing an item at a blacksmith will probably cost more than this.

Just try to keep a full stack of repair kits (10) on you, and fill up when you run into a merchant that has them. If you are running out for some reason, you can buy some extra and put them in your stash.

You can use repair kits in the middle of battle. Literally in the middle. If you're spinning in the air in the middle of a special attack and you get a message about a broken item, just pause and fix your item with a repair kit. It will be fixed when you come out of the pause menu, and you can continue fighting after you hit the ground.